# Formatting of text in a textblock in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I am have a text which is has bold, underline and italic html characters. For example

```
<b> hello<b> how are <i>you</i>. I am <u>fine</u>
```

I have to show it in formatted form in a textblock on WP7. I have a listbox like this

```
<ListBox x:Name="LBayaDetail" Loaded="LBayaDetail_Loaded" Margin="6,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid x:Name="ayaContent" Margin="0,6,0,0" Hold="ayaContent_Hold" Tap="ayaContent_Tap" Loaded="ayaContent_Loaded" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="6"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="6" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid Background="#FFC5AC88" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="ayaIndex" Text="{Binding aya}" FontSize="36" Margin="0" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <Image Source="{Binding BookmarkImage}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="48" Height="48" Margin="0,0,0,12" />
                                    <Image Source="{Binding NoteImage}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="48" Height="48" Margin="0,0,0,12" />
                                    <Image Source="{Binding TagImage}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="48" Height="48" Margin="0,0,0,12" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="#FFC5AC88" x:Name="Media" Tap="Media_Tap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Image Source="/Images/Media-Play(1).png" Width="30" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            </Grid>
                            <!--ini pak dimana tempat untuk ayat dan translasi-->
                            <Grid  Grid.Column="2" Background="#FFAC9574" Margin="6,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="aya" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding text}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontFamily="/Fonts/me_quran2.ttf#me_quran2" FontSize="{Binding FontSizeAya}" Foreground="Black" Margin="24,0,12,-12" TextAlignment="Right" Visibility="{Binding visibility1}" />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="6,0,0,0" Background="#FFAC9574" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <StackPanel>

                                    <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding visibility2}" x:Name="translation" Text="{Binding translation}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontFamily="/Fonts/ARIALUNI.TTF#Arial Unicode MS" FontSize="{Binding FontSizeTranslation}" Foreground="#FF5D2A07" Margin="12,6,6,0" />
                                    <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding visibility3}" x:Name="translation2" Text="{Binding translation2}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontFamily="/Fonts/ARIALUNI.TTF#Arial Unicode MS" FontSize="{Binding FontSizeTranslation}" Foreground="DarkGreen" Margin="12,20,6,0" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                            <!-- -->
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

I fetch from database like

```
App.Listxyz = (Application.Current as App).db.SelectList<Aya>(strSelect);
```

And assign it to Listbox like this

```
LBayaDetail.ItemsSource = App.ListAyaBySurah;
```

And shows the text as it is and do not format it which is obvious. I searched for it and I was able to format individual textblock by using "RUN" but I am unable to do it in listbox.
I also tried to use HTMLTextBlock but it also doesn't format the text and shows it like this

```
Hi
How 
Are 
You
```

Any help will be much appreciated that how do I format a textblock with different text decorations.

Thanks

Comment: My guess is you'll have to resort to creating `TextBlock`s with different Font style properties at code behind after parsing the string yourself. See for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.fontweight(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `I was able to format individual textblock by using "RUN" but I am unable to do it in listbox.`  <-- what does this mean?  Why not?

Answer (score 0):

You should place a grid and a stackpanel inside the listbox. Something like the following

```
                <Grid>          
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock Padding="0,5,0,2" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                            <Run Text="{Binding test}" FontWeight="Bold" /> <Run Text="{Binding test2}" />
                            <LineBreak/>
                            <Run Text="{Binding test3}" />
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
```

Comment: I have a text of variable lengths. for example one text will be <b> Learn </b> to speak <b> politely </b> and act <i> sensibly </i> and always speak <i> truth </i>

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is:

```
public class FormattedText
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsBold { get; set; }
    public bool IsItalic { get; set; }
    public bool IsUnderlined { get; set; }
}
```

Have a method that converts the HTML you stored in your db to a list of the class you have above

example:
From this:

```
<b> hello<b> how are <i>you</i>. I am <u>fine</u>
```

to this:

1. First element:

   - Text = "hello"
   - IsBold = true
   - skip what not needed since bool default value is false
2. Second element

   - Text =" how are"
   - skip what not needed since bool default value is false
3. Third item

   - Text ="you"
   - IsItalic=true;
   - skip what not needed since bool default value is false
     and so on....

and then have another method that from that list creates a list of Runs to be added to your `TextBlock` or 
maybe create a custom `TextBlock` witch take the `List<FormattedText>` from `DataContext` and process it by adding the `Run` elements to self